# GRUB configuration not responding

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, configuration, bootloader

Recently, I tried to reconfigure GRUB to boot kernel 3.2 instead of 3.4, but by booting, GRUB is not responding to any changes I make in the `grub.cfg` file. Editing `/etc/default/grub` and updating it with `update-grub` doesn't bring any errors and changes and ends with `done.`. Kernel 3.4 is always booting, whatever I do. Google is speechless.

Comment: Please post your /etc/default/grub and your /boot/grub/grub.cfg (as it looks immediately after running "update-grub" with the /etc/default/grub that you post). Also, why do you have a 3.4 kernel installed if you don't intend to use it by default? Do you plan to sometimes use it or could it just be removed to simplify things?

Answer (score 0):

Default grub menu entry can be switched using `GRUB_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` file.
If your kernel 3.2 entry is 7th in the list - the easiest way to set to default would be making following change in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=7
```

And then executing `sudo update-grub2` to update grub configuration.

Comment: This answer is the result of the comment thread. Question needs to be updated.

Answer (score -1):

If you really have kernel version 3.2 installed in your system, it will be added to grub menu automatically after you do

```
sudo update-grub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: OP already wrote that `update-grub` does not help.

Comment: GRUB doesn't react to any updating, but grub.cfg changes. Kernel 3.2 is the 7th entry in the menu. Setting it to default doesn't work. Trying to set timeout doesn't work either.

Comment: @Andrejs Cainikovs This means that the conditional clause in my answer is not satisfied [properly].

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs yes, it exists and is chosen in grub.cfg, but by rebooting, just 3.4 boots without letting my choose between versions. no reaction, that's the problem.

Comment: @stef, now I'm lost. As per your last comment - you cannot select the 3.2 entry? I am right?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs its in the list, but i cannot automatically boot it.. changes to the GRUB configuration don't respond

Comment: @stef, please check my answer. Hope it helps. And yes, please edit your question to indicate that you have a problem with default menu entry, to make it more clear.